# select dynamically option from select-box using jQuery/javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding dynamically a selected box items.

I want when I check a check-box set the value or the selected option of all the additional selected-box to the selected option of the first selected box.

So I'm using the following code to add dynamically input fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {

    var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
    var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
    //added data-index and outer..class
    $(".form_field_outer").append(
      `<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}">
            <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> 
            <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                                            <select  class="form-control maintCostField"  name="rows[${index}][id_casting]" id="id_casting" >
                                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                            @foreach($castings as $casting)
                                            <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body ">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div> </div></div> `);


    $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field").first().prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pl-4 pr-0 check-button">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0 d-inline-block">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkAll">
                                        <span class="custom-control-label">&nbsp;</span>
                                    </label>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
      <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="1">
        <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
            <select class="form-control maintCostField" name="rows[1][id_casting]" id="id_casting">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              @foreach($castings as $casting)
              <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg top-right-button mr-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
          </div>
          <div class="casting_details">
            <div class="casting_details2">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-6">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I want when I Add a multiple additional selected-box and I check the checked box all the additional selected-box get the same selected option of the first selected-box.

That means when I add the first row and I select option1 , all the additional rows should get the  option1 as the first additional row.

I'm still a beginner in jQuery and JavaScript, is it possible to do this and is it possible to do it with jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set unique id for each select item: `id="id_casting${index}"`.

Then you set selected option if your check box has checked:

```
var checked = $("#checkAll").is(':checked')
if (checked)
     $("#id_casting" + index).val($("#id_casting").find(":selected").val());
```

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function () {
               
                var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
                var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
                //added data-index and outer..class
                $(".form_field_outer").append(
                    `<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}">
            <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row">
            <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                                            <select  class="form-control maintCostField"  name="rows[${index}][id_casting]" id="id_casting${index}" >
                                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                            @foreach($castings as $casting)
                                            <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body ">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div> </div></div> `);


                var checked = $("#checkAll").is(':checked')
                if (checked)
                     $("#id_casting" + index).val($("#id_casting").find(":selected").val());

                $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
                $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field").first().prop("disabled", true);
            });
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pl-4 pr-0 check-button">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0 d-inline-block">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkAll">
            <span class="custom-control-label">&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
                <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="1">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                            <select class="form-control maintCostField" name="rows[1][id_casting]" id="id_casting">
                                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                @foreach($castings as $casting)
                                <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body ">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg top-right-button mr-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="casting_details">
                            <div class="casting_details2">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-6">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your ansxer and your help , it works well form me , now I want do the same with a date input , And I did the following code :  `$("#date_fin_contrat" + index).val($("#date_fin_contrat"));` n but doesn't get tha value of the first additional date input

Comment: Use the value of date: `$("#date_fin_contrat" + index).val($("#date_fin_contrat").val());`